# Issue Creating a Flowing Sankey Diagram in R Using gganimate

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, sankey-diagram, gganimate

I am using the following guide in an attempt to create a flowing sankey diagram: https://www.hvitfeldt.me/blog/recreate-sankey-flow-chart/#r-packages. My understanding is that this approach (i.e. gganimate(p)) utilizes an old and now unsupported version of gganimate. I am attempting to adapt the code to work with the new gganimate. I am using the code provided below.

I expected a result like the one on the the blog:
[image]

i.e. slow moving and with individual points. What I get with my code are fast moving "points" with each point actually being represented by a series of five points:

[image]

Any help replicating the blog product using the new gganimate would be much appreciated.

CODE:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

sigmoid <- function(x_from, x_to, y_from, y_to, scale = 5, n = 100) {
  x <- seq(-scale, scale, length = n)
  y <- exp(x) / (exp(x) + 1)
  tibble(x = (x + scale) / (scale * 2) * (x_to - x_from) + x_from,
         y = y * (y_to - y_from) + y_from)
}

n_points <- 400
data <- tibble(from = rep(4, n_points),
               to = sample(1:4, n_points, TRUE),
               color = sample(c("A", "B"), n_points, TRUE)) 

p <- map_df(seq_len(nrow(data)), 
            ~ sigmoid(0, 1, as.numeric(data[.x, 1]), as.numeric(data[.x,                     
 2])) %>%
          mutate(time = row_number() + .x,
                 y = y + runif(1, -0.25, 0.25))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, frame = time)) +
    geom_point()+transition_time(time) 

p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have 499 values in `time`, more than the default number of frames that get rendered (100). When you use `transition_time(time)` it's including all the data, even for frames "in between" the ones that are rendered. That's why you're seeing groups of 5 dots.

You can either:

1) replace with `transition_manual(time)` so it just uses 100 frames of your data, discarding the ones in between, or

2) keep the `transition_time(time)` but render using `animate(p, nframes = 499)`, so that you keep all the frames.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Both ways work. Could you potentially shed some light on why I there are 499 values in time being generated and also how I might export this animated chart to be able to share?

Comment: Inspect your data before the `ggplot` call by removing the preceding `%>%`, and I think you'll see that time varies from 2 to 500. I saved the file by right clicking on the animation in the Viewer tab, but I think there are other ways to save if you look online.

Comment: Perfect! You have been a huge help. Sorry for all the questions but what about speeding up and slowing down the animation? Adjusting the fps in animate kind of does the trick but it makes everything look choppy and no longer smooth.

Comment: Animate gives you `nframes`, `duration`, and `fps`, any two of which will together determine how many frames are shown and how much time between them.